# Lost iPhone. 2FA

Tags: iphone, icloud

Initial situation:

You are new to the Apple world, but you know that if you have 2 iPhones and one is lost, you can use the other iPhone to lock the lost one via the Find My app. But they must be connected to the same Apple ID.

But what if you only have a single phone and that phone even has the trusted phone number for 2FA from the Apple ID.

Then couldn't the thief reset the phone or iCloud with the phone number?

And would that mean you'll never find your phone again because you can't locate it? If you think buying a new iPhone, signing in with the Apple ID and then locking it like that doesn't work, 2FA is required and we don't have the phone number.

What now?

Comment: If your iPhone is stolen : lock the sim of the phone by calling your mobile provider : 2FA will no longer work with this SIM.

Comment: By then it will be too late...

Comment: Don‘t you lock your phone with FaceID/good passphrase?

Comment: It is provided with a code. But by cracking the code, couldn't the thief take over my entire iCloud?
Could it be extremely dangerous to be signed into iCloud with just one device?

Comment: Did you set the „wipe after 10 failed code entries“ option? Unless your code is super-simple or super-short (short enough for somebody to see and remember what you are typing), this should protect your phone.

Answer (score 1):

In the, quite ordinary, case of having only a single phone - you should remember that other devices can also be setup for 2FA. If you have a Mac, an iPad, iPod Touch or similar - you can get the 2FA code displayed on there. That will allow you to use a web-browser with icloud.com to locate and lock (or even remote wipe) the lost phone.

If a thief steals the phone with the trusted phone number for 2FA, he wouldn't be able to just immediately "reset your iCloud" or anything like that:

First of all, the iPhone would usually be protected by a pass code and possibly biometrics like TouchID and FaceID. It is your responsibility to choose a sensible pass code, so that the thief cannot guess this with a few attempts (i.e. don't choose 123456 or 111111). If the thief tries to guess too many times, the phone introduces an increasing delay before allowing a new attempt. In addition, you can set the phone to auto-wipe after a high number of failed pass code attempts.

Secondly, the thief cannot just request a 2FA code to be sent by text for example. In order to be able to do that, he would need to first know your iCloud account password. It is your responsibility to choose a reasonably complex and unique password, and keep it secret.

Finally, you should call your phone company and get your SIM card cancelled/locked when you discover the theft. This will stop it from receiving texts (as well as stopping the thief from using the SIM card in other devices should the PIN code be guessable or disabled).